# d-link 2640B cannot access control panel, page refreshes, cannot reset to factory settings

Tags: router

I recently moved from 1 country to another. So I had to lag all my equipment with me. Even though I had dlink router with me in the airplane cabin, it seems I smoked it.

When I try to access admin panel, it just refreshes login page and nothing else happens. If I put wrong password it shows me password is wrong.

When I try to reset to factory settings it hangs, I have red lights and it never reboots so I suppose it hangs.

RIP? or is there any hope for it?

Comment: Have you pressed and held the reset down for 30 seconds with power to the unit?

Comment: @Ramhound as per manual, I turned it off, than I pressed reset button and while holding it turned on power, waited for 5 secs. Is 30 sec thing for this router?